# How to stop Alert box reloading in same session

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've used the code below - from https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_alert.asp - to create an alert box that goes away when the user clicks on the "x" button inside the box. But the box appears again whenever a user loads another page.

I’d like users to only see this box once; ie, it doesn't reappear again after they have clicked it.

New to this site and javascript - would be grateful for suggestions on what should be added to the script below so the box doesn't reappear for a user once they've clicked it.

```
<div class="alert">
<span class="closebtn"onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none';">&times;</span> 
<a style="color:#fff" href="//www.google.com/">Click this link</a>

<script>
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("closebtn");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
acc[i].onclick = function(){
var div = this.parentElement;
div.style.opacity = "0";
setTimeout(function(){ div.style.display = "none"; }, 600);
}
}
</script>

<style>
/* The alert message box */
.alert {
position: fixed; z-index:100; bottom: 0px; width:100%;
padding: 20px;
background-color: #f44336; /* Red */
color: white;
/* margin-bottom: 15px; */
}

/* The close button */
.closebtn {
margin-left: 15px;
color: white;
font-weight: bold;
float: right;
font-size: 22px;
line-height: 20px;
cursor: pointer;
transition: 0.3s;
}

/* When moving the mouse over the close button */
.closebtn:hover {
color: black;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Use local storage or cookie to check for subsequent requests

Comment: Thanks @Mayank Pandeyz - I'm a javascript noob; is it possible to show what should be added to this script using local storage?